# Fastest way to calculate a value with its group in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a matrix like this:

```
Group   A  
1   |   1  
5   |   2  
1   |   3  
2   |   4  
4   |   5  
2   |   6  
2   |   7  
3   |   8  
2   |   9  
3   |   10  
5   |   11  
1   |   12
```

In this matrix A column is items and Group is the groups of A column. I have another matrix like this:

```
A    Value  
1   |   5  
2   |   3.5  
3   |   2  
4   |   0  
5   |   1  
6   |   2.5  
7   |   4  
8   |   3  
9   |   0  
10  |   0  
11  |   1.5  
12  |   0
```

Expected result:

```
A    Value  
1   |   5  
2   |   3.5  
3   |   2  
4   |   3.25  
5   |   1  
6   |   2.5  
7   |   4  
8   |   3  
9   |   3.25  
10  |   3 
11  |   1.5  
12  |   3.5
```

*I find from first Matrix that 1, 3, and 12 have same group, and then for calculate the value of 12 I Calculate average of values of 1 and 3.*

In the second matrix value column is value of column A, I want to calculate zero values for every Item in A column with average of other items in the same group. 
I used this:

```
for h=1:size(Matrix2,1)
    group=find(Matrix1(:,1)==Matrix2(h,1));
    group_items=find(Matrix1(:,2)==Matrix1(group,2));
    f=ismember(Matrix2(:,1),Matrix1(group_items,1));
    if Matrix2(h,2)==0
        Matrix2(h,2)=sum(Matrix2(f,2))/size(nonzeros(f),1);
    end
end
```

but this is very slow when the second matrix is large.
Is there a faster way?

Comment: thank you, can you give me an example?

Comment: Expected output for the sample?

Comment: Are you sure you second matrix is right? Are you not just trying to find the average value per group from your first matrix? So for example you have three values in group `1` i.e. `1`, `3` and `12` so shouldn't `1` in your second matrix be `(1+3+12)/3`?

Comment: expected result for value of 12 is: (5+2)/2

Comment: Please add an explanation to your question of how you get those values for 12. It is not clear.

Comment: I find from first Matrix that 1, 3, and 12 have same group, and then for calculate the value of 12 I Calculate average of values of 1 and 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this any better?

```
 M1 = [1       1  
       5       2  
       1       3  
       2       4  
       4       5  
       2       6  
       2       7  
       3       8  
       2       9  
       3       10  
       5       11  
       1       12 ]


 M2 = [1       5  
       2       3.5  
       3       2  
       4       0  
       5       1  
       6       2.5  
       7       4  
       8       3  
       9       0  
       10      0  
       11      1.5  
       12      0 ]

Z = find(M2(:,2)==0)'
m = zeros(size(Z));
for k = 1:size(Z,2)
    r = Z(k);
    val = M2(M1(:,1)==M1(r,1),2);
    m(k) = mean(val(val~=0))
end
M_out = M2;
M_out(M2(:,2)==0,2) = m
```

Comment: thank you, isn't  there any solution without using loop?

Comment: Probably if you restructured your inputs (for starters I would make them single column vectors, why do you need the columns of just consecutive numbers...) but there really is nothing wrong with loops unless your Matlab is 5 years out of date. First check to see if this looping solution provides a decent speed-up. Maybe it's enough.

Comment: maybe this is a better way but it still is slow.